# How to compare rows from the same table and update accordingly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a query to compare the table row values based on same id and update the status column accordingly. If the values of the same ID matches, then update status to MATCHED else NOT MATCHED

| ID | Value | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | MATCHED |
| 2 | BBB | MATCHED |
| 3 | CCC | NOT MATCHED |
| 1 | AAA | MATCHED |
| 2 | BBB | MATCHED |
| 3 | CXX | NOT MATCHED |

Comment: @lemon I have tried to do a self join but it will return duplicate rows and also trying out to update the status column accordingly...

Comment: @AaronBertrand it will only have 2 of same ID

Comment: why has this table not a unique column that also defines an order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid self join operations, and use a couple of window functions to check when max over an id is same as min value over the same id.

```
SELECT ID,
       Status_, 
       CASE WHEN MIN(Value_) OVER(PARTITION BY ID)
               = MAX(Value_) OVER(PARTITION BY ID)
            THEN 'Matched'
            ELSE 'Not Matched'
       END AS Status_ 
FROM tab
```

If you already have a status value, and you need to update it, you can use the same query inside an update statement as follows:

```
WITH cte AS ( 
    SELECT tab.*, 
           CASE WHEN MIN(Value_) OVER(PARTITION BY ID)
                   = MAX(Value_) OVER(PARTITION BY ID)
                THEN 'Matched'
                ELSE 'Not Matched'
           END AS newStatus 
    FROM tab
)
UPDATE cte
SET Status_ = newStatus
WHERE NOT Status_ = newStatus;
```

**Output**:

| ID | Value_ | Status_ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | Matched |
| 1 | AAA | Matched |
| 2 | BBB | Matched |
| 2 | BBB | Matched |
| 3 | CCC | Not Matched |
| 3 | CXX | Not Matched |

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Z6XaGSzn).

Comment: you have seen the sql server tag?

Comment: must have misread it definitely, thanks @nbk

Comment: @lemon So the 2nd solution above is to update the status column from the Common Table Expression CTE's result. However, may I know what is the logic of the aggregate function MIN() and MAX() used? IIs it mandatory since Partitioning is used?

Comment: In this case, MAX and MIN are not aggregate function. They're effectively the corresponding homonimous window functions, that allow you to keep the same amount of rows but check for values in the whole table. You can't use aggregate functions here because the cte is currently driving the update on each single record (aggregate functions reduce the amount of records).

Comment: that doesn't work https://dbfiddle.uk/DlbWevvb

Comment: There's one non-matching value, why would you expect a match?